# How to clear a plot from panel?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm drawing a plot to a wxPython panel using matplotlib with the following code:

```
self.plot_data = self.axes.plot(
        t,c, 
        linewidth=1,
        color=(1, 0.8, 0),
        )[0]
```

Anyone know how I can delete/clear the plot from the panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the remove method of the returned `Line2D` object.:

```
self.plot_data.remove()
self.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
```

The draw call is needed to re-draw the canvas.  The OO interface is lazy and does not trigger rerendering the graph unless told to.